# How i can execute Jquery only on selected button

Tags: jquery, button, message, slide

For example using this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").bind("click",function(){
    $("p").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Got two buttons- A and B. What i want to do is that when i press A, i get message:"This is A button", when i press B, i get message:" This is B button". But right now when i press A button i get A button message and B button meesage. What i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

A little more context would hel.  But what you are probably going to want to do is the following:

```
<p id="para-a">...</p>
<p id="para-b">...</p>
<input type="button" id="button-a" />
<input type="button" id="button-b" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button#button-a').bind("click", function() { $('p#para-a').slideToggle(); } );
      $('button#button-b').bind("click", function() { $('p#para-b').slideToggle(); } );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonA").click(function(){
        alert("A");
    });

    $("#buttonB").click(function(){
        alert("B");
    });
});
```

Having:

```
<button id="buttonA">A</button>
<button id="buttonB">B</button>
```